# Magento 2 SALES Order and REPORT Orders Export data qis inconsistent

Tags: magento2, sales-order, export

1. Two different operating places in the background.
2. Choose the same time (one day) for testing.
3. The output is different.
4. SALES Order count is same as my database query result.

This is SALES Orders
[image]

This is  REPORTS Orders
[image]

The results of the query after time conversion.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. check if the statistics data is up to date. Data for the report needs to be rebuilt by cron or manually
2. check your timezone settings. I had issues with this in magento 1 when my timezone was not UTC, and orders where placed around 0am +/- a few hours 
   This might also be an issue for the results of the db query in comparison to any other data, because the date in the database is actually stored in UTC, but shown converted to your timezone in the backend

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad the problem has been solved.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14500